# AWS Lambda. Get caller`s ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using aws lambda function in which I need to handle the ip address of the caller. How can I get the ip address of the one who called the function?

I do not use API Gateway to call the function, but call the function directly using ARN.

Is there a way to get the ip of the caller of the function without using API Gateway?

Comment: The issue is that while you can call a Lambda through, for example, the AWS CLI, there are many more ways for the Lambda to be called.  For example, if you have an S3 event, what good would the internal IP do?  Same thing with an SNS event.  If you're treating this as an HTTP type service then API gateway would be your best bet.

Comment: Have you checked if the "caller IP" is on the `event` object inside the handler when you call the function? If it is not, there will not be any way for you to add it.

Comment: You can [use AWS Lambda behind an Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-alb.html) which will invoke your Lambda with an event that includes `x-forwarded-for`.